# IOS FaceBook SDK, Event Manager requiring update FB SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, swift-package-manager

I used SwiftUI in my project. Add FaceBook SDK v9 with swift package manager according to FB instructions. FB Event Manager asking me update my SDK because it's outdated. I don't understand how it's possible. I use latest version. App is already in App Store. I can't advertise my app due this. Please help.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's a facebook bug, after 3 days passed, fb allow me create adv compain. But it still shows me warning i need update SDK.

Comment: please leave this as a comment